# count distinct values from multiple column hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table like the following

`Id  col1 col2 col3
1   Yes  No    No
2   No   Yes   No
3   Yes  No    No
4   No   Yes   No`

I'm looking for a hive query to display results in the following format

`Value   col1  col2  col3
Yes      2     2      0
No       2     2      4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      val                                     as value
           ,count (case when pos = 0 then 1 end)    as col1 
           ,count (case when pos = 1 then 1 end)    as col2
           ,count (case when pos = 2 then 1 end)    as col3 

from        mytable
            lateral view posexplode(array(col1,col2,col3)) pe

group by   val
```

---

```
+-------+------+------+------+
| value | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+-------+------+------+------+
| No    |    2 |    2 |    4 |
| Yes   |    2 |    2 |    0 |
+-------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Thank you. nice to know about posexplode